# Mysql ROUND return worng value?

Tags: mysql

I have a rule table:

```
rule_id  basic   hra  conveyance  medical
      1    0.5  0.25         800     1250
```

I run this query:

```
SELECT ROUND( 16405 ) AS `CTC`, ROUND( 16405 * r.basic ) AS `basic`,
ROUND( 16405 * r.hra ) AS `hra`, r.conveyance AS `conveyance`,
r.medical AS `medical` 
FROM `rule` AS r
WHERE `r`.`rule_id` =1
```

It returns the following:

```
CTC     basic   hra conveyance  medical  
16405   8202    4101    800          1250
```

The value of basic should be 8203 but it returns 8202.

Comment: `16405 * 0.5` equals `8202.5`. Are you really getting `5742`?

Comment: I guess `basic` is `FLOAT` rather than `DECIMAL`, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ROUND` use `CEIL` - it will round up your value.

```
CEIL( 16405 * r.basic ) AS  `basic`
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the rules as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round):

> - For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half away from zero” or “round toward nearest” rule: **A value with a fractional part
>     of .5 or greater is rounded up to the next integer if positive** or down
>     to the next integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded away
>     from zero.) A value with a fractional part less than .5 is rounded
>     down to the next integer if positive or up to the next integer if
>     negative.
> - **For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library**. On many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest
>     even" rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest
>     even integer.

According to your last edit so far, 8202.5 is getting rounded towards zero. That probably means that you are not using an exact data type like `DECIMAL`. If your column type is `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, the rounding algorithm is platform-dependent (and you're also subject to floating point precision issues).

You can check whether explicit casting solves the issue:

```
SELECT ROUND(8202.5), ROUND(CAST(8202.5 AS DECIMAL))
```